# Tilde in url with css modules does not work

Tags: css, webpack, css-modules

Do you have some example config that works?

setting for webpack:

```js
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: ['style-loader', {
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
      modules: true,
      localIdentName: '[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
    },
  }, 'sass-loader'],
},
```

Usage:

```scss
background: url('~assets/arrow-white.svg') center no-repeat;
```

Output:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/arrow-white.svg'
```

I can omit `~` or use `~/../assets` and it works , but I would like to use it just `~`.

- Probably relevant bug: CSS modules break build if used with `~` https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/589

Comment: the problem is that css-modules mode changes path resolution and doesn't respect webpack module resolution

Comment: I struggled with this issue for a while in my angular 5 app the last few days. deleted my node_modules folder, npm installed, then the issue went away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this package https://github.com/P0lip/url-tilde-loader

```js
// In your webpack config
{
  test: /\.s?css$/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    {
      loader: "css-loader",
      options: {
        modules: true,
      },
    },
    {
      loader: 'url-tilde-loader'
      options: {
        replacement: '~/../', // string to replace with
        traverse: false, // use manual traversing
      },
    },
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just copy your comment in order that you may close this question

> the problem is that css-modules mode changes path resolution and
>   doesn't respect webpack module resolution

Comment: my comment was answer to some other comment, which is now deleted, and is not answer to main queston.

Comment: If this was the correct answer the considerate thing yo do would be to mark the answer as community wiki, since it is someone else’s answer.

Comment: Thank for the advice, but how may I mark the answer as a community wiki ?